# Calling an assembly function from another file

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following code to compute square of a number which works perfectly:

```
        .section .data

        .section .text

        .globl _start
        .globl square

_start:
        pushl $10

        call square
        addl $4, %esp

        movl %eax, %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80

        .type square,@function

square:
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp
        movl 8(%ebp), %eax

        imull %eax, %eax

end_square:
        movl %ebp, %esp
        popl %ebp
        ret
```

I want to call the function `square` from another file named `square_test.s`. This is my attempt:

```
        .section .data

        .section .text

        .globl _start

_start:

        pushl $12
        call square
        addl $4, %esp

        movl %eax, %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

But when linking it throws me this error:

```
$ as --32 square_test.s -o square_test.o
$ as --32 square.s -o square.o
$ ld -m elf_i386 square.o square_test.o -o square_test
square_test.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
square.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

How should I fix this ?

Comment: It says "multiple definition of _start", doesn't it? And clearly you have two of those. So what's the solution? Keep the one you want, delete the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the above comments, finally I made it work. These are the two files:

```
# file name: isolated_square.s

        .section .data

        .section .text

        .globl square

        .type square,@function

square:
        pushl %ebp
        movl %esp, %ebp
        movl 8(%ebp), %eax

        imull %eax, %eax

end_square:
        movl %ebp, %esp
        popl %ebp
        ret
```

And this is the other file:

```
        # file name: square_test.s
        .section .data

        .section .text

        .globl _start

_start:

        pushl $12
        call square
        addl $4, %esp

        movl %eax, %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

And this is how you need to execute it:

```
$ as --32 isolated_square.s -o isolated_square.o
$ as --32 square_test.s -o square_test.o
$ ld -m elf_i386 isolated_square.o square_test.o -o square_test
$ ./square_test
$ echo $?
144
```

Comment: You can do it all in one step with `gcc -m32 -static -nostdlib -no-pie *.s -o square_test`.  (It used to be that `gcc -nostdlib` was all you needed, but default-pie is a thing now.)

Answer (score 2):

You have two global symbols named "_start" (one in each file).  If you want to link the files together, you'll have to rename one of them to something other than "_start", or make one of them non-global (remove the .globl directive).